# GPX track appears scaled down and in center of world using standalone PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, gpx, standalone

I'm trying to load a GPX-track as a layer in PyQGIS (standalone) but the track appears entirely on the wrong scale and position (scaled down in the middle of the equator). When I load the file manually everything is great. When I use the following code I run into issues

```
GPX_path = "C:\\Users\\dorus\Desktop\\TU Delft\\2021\\Team DSM\\QGIS\\Projects\\GPX\\GPX1.gpx?type=track"
gpx_layer = QgsVectorLayer(GPX_path, "Route", "gpx")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(gpx_layer)
```

The code is almost entirely copied from the cookbook so I'm a little lost.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with assumed projection

Comment: Look at the properties for the two covers, in "Source", check the assigned CRS.